# How to remove the white border around the image in splash screen in full screen

Tags: android, xml

I am currently working on a splash screen with an image view. The problem is that when the splash screen is shown, there is a white border around the image. So that the splash screen shows the image with the white border around. I would like to remove the white border completely. Is there any one who know the reason for this or any suggestion?

Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageViewSplash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@string/splashImageContentDescription" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you have an arbitrary View in the layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I apply a transparent background in the theme/style I use for my splash pages, this way I don't have to distort the image being displayed to fit the screen size of the device.  This works particularly well when using PNG files that contain a transparent background.

Here's the style I use for this "Transparent" theme:

```
    <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
```

You then apply this theme to the splash activity in your application manifest as follows:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.masseria.homework9.SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I have tried to make the background color of the relativelayout and the in transparent, it still doesn't work.

Comment: How are you loading your image into the ImageView?

Comment: I load the image wwith img.setImageReosource(R.drawable.image) in code.

Comment: Excellent!  Not the one-line solution that everyone was hoping for, but works quite well.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you could remove everything from your layout except for the `ImageView`. So it would look like this:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ImageViewSplash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@string/splashImageContentDescription" />
```

Then you could play around with the scaleType on the image until you found one that filled the screen. If none of that works, I would suggest increasing the resolution of your image file.

Comment: Ah, you may need to set adjustViewBounds to false. Perhaps it's shrinking the size of the view.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. Since I use dialog to display the splash screen, so i need to set it to dialog, not the actual screen