# Android drawing white border around fullscreen RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I just noticed that android is drawing a small white border (1px I guess) around my RelativeLayout in my fullscreen activity. I have set the RelativeLayout's height and width to `match_parent`, but it still has that small border around it.

My activity style:

```
<style name="Theme.Fullscreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/black_87</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black_87</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/black_54</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>

    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

My fullscreen activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there something I need to add to the layout that it gets rid of this white small border?

Comment: Why have you set margin for the layout: `layout_margin="-2dp"` ?

Comment: Tried to add that to see if that would solve the issue, but it didn't. Should have removed that before posting, sorry

Comment: try this theme: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

Comment: Didn't fix the problem.

Comment: If so try making it transparent: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15930764/4747587

Comment: Nope, white border is still there :(

Comment: I tried your layout and the style. Works fine for me. Did you try this out in other devices ? probably a device specific issue.

Comment: Emulator having the same issue. I was supposed to apply the theme you gave me to the relativelayout, right?

Comment: No to the <activity> in the manifest. I didn't try out the theme that i suggested, but the one that you have posted. And it works perfectly.

Comment: Using the theme you gave me results in a crash as I need to use a appcompat theme.