# How can I get rid of the logo white background in splash screen Flutter?

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

I'm trying to get rid of this white background that appears around my logo.
[image]

I was able to change the background from here android/app/src/main/res/drawable/launch_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/back_color"/>

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

but the image is showing white background even though the image in the asset has no white background. How can I remove this white background?

Note: I'm using Flutter in Android Studio

Comment: maybe there’s white in another file? There's different launch_background.xml for android 12 and prior versions.

Comment: where can I find it ?

Comment: I searched in the project, but I found only this one

Comment: It's in the same directory as this one but with v21 or similar suffix. If that isn’t true then there must be some problem with color item...  Check by adding another color value and see if it changes.

Comment: I have two versions for style.xml file, but launch_background is just one. The issue isn't with the whole background color as I can change it easily. but the logo shows a white shape around it, even though the logo is just red. I don't know why.

Comment: hmm ok. It’s prolly some masking issue then.. try reuploading your assets following this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085753/android-studio-image-asset-launcher-icon-background-color

Comment: but in flutter I don't have this option. + the app logo launcher is set already from flutterflow and it is working fine but inside the app is the issue.

Comment: cab you please see my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78246859/why-flutterflow-app-is-showing-two-splash-screens-when-testing-on-android-device

Comment: you can add assets from android studio by opening android module or use asset generator and paste it into res folder appropriately . I suggest using `flutter native splash` package as it will do all the config for all platforms. I suppose then the duplicate splash screen would also be fixed. You could add the `styles.xml` code along with updated `launch_background.xml`

Answer (score 0):

change it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />
        
    </item>
    
    
    
    
    
</layer-list>
```

Comment: but I don't want the background to be white. I want it in red, I just don't want the logo to have this white background.

Comment: change this gravity="center"

Comment: I did. still the same

Comment: check your image has white space like this

Comment: No it doesn't, I don't know where this white come from

Comment: i think it is transparent problem you can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15930764/20259506)

Comment: I tried that and it is still the same <\3