# Why flutterflow app is showing two splash screens when testing on Android Device>

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

I have added a splash screen on FlutterFlow from Settings> App assets. When testing on web it works just fine. but when I imported the project into Android Studio and tested it on a real android device, two splash screens are showing. As you can see here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fhQ-T6_hVUXsRHClKfm6JRa1g-uiOX5P/view?usp=sharing

I added the second one(the one with red background). but it is showing the default flutter splash screen but replacing flutter icon with the app icon.
How can I remove the first splash screen and only have the one I added?

Answer (score 1):

The default splash screen cannot be overridden with Dart/Flutter alone.You can use [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash/example)
pakage to create the splash screen. And comment this lines of your `android\app\src\main\res\drawable\launch_background.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <!--comment this item tag-->
    <!-- <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />
        
    </item> -->
    
    
    
    
    
</layer-list>
```